# Performance Issue in Hadoop,HBase & Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase, hdfs

I am working on Migrating a Data from SQL Database to Hadoop, in which I have used HBase & Hadoop as well. I have successfully imported my data from SQL db to Hadoop, HBase and Hive. But the problem is the Performance of the System. I was getting the results of millions of entries within 5-10 minutes in SQL Db, but it takes around 1 hr to fetch 10 million of data from HBase & Hive. Can anyone help me on this to improve the Performance of my Hadoop System.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data in HBase is only 'indexed' by rowkey. If you're querying in Hive on anything other than rowkey prefixes, you will generally be performing a full table scan.

There are some optimizations that can be made with HBase filters e.g., when using a FamilyFilter, you may be able to skip entire regions, but I doubt Hive is doing that.

How to improve performance depends on how your data is shaped and what analysis you need to perform on it. When performing frequent ad-hoc analysis, you may be better served by exporting data from HBase into something like Parquet files on HDFS and running your analysis against those with Hive (or Drill or Spark, Imapala, etc).

Comment: Thnx for quick reply Angus. By tuning the JVM performance now I am able to fetch the 10,00,000 lakh records within 8 Minutes in Birt integrated Hive - HBase, but what I wanna to fetch 1crore of entries withing 10 minutes. I have tried Apache Spark for high query processing with no luck for my goal. Is there any way to achieve this of fetching such amount of data within few minutes. What about Impala ?? Will it work for me ??Looking forward for your reply. Any tutorial or any other reference will be a great help.